# Identity Server 4 Changing of Profile Data. How Does Client Know?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am a bit confused of what happens in this situation. Say you have Identity Server 4 (IS4) with Asp.net Identity Core (IC). the user comes in logins in and you get profile information (name, email and etc).

Now the client is probably going to store that information. Now what happens if a user changes their information(changes their name for instance).

How do clients know about this change?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a trigger in IdentityServer to notify your application. This doesn't mean you can't build something to do this. A simple solution can be to register your application so it can be notified when something changes in the user profile.

Otherwise you can check when a token is received. You could use an in-memory list of users with an expiration time (set it to a day or so). If a user is not in the list check the userinfo endpoint. You cannot use the info from the token, because that is not recent. Being not in the list of users doesn't mean the token was issued recently.

Comment: Yeah, once the identity token has been issued (or user info endpoint called) that's it, the client app has loaded in the claims. You'll need something custom to detect or check for profile changes.

Comment: if you make a new endpoint on IS4, how do you go about protecting that end point?

Comment: To get the refreshed data?

Comment: The endpoint already exists, you just need to call it: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html or check the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think [userinfo endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html) may help you to achieve what you want. It can give you user claims provided you've got a valid access token